# export fbx and obj problem materials

Tags: materials, export, import

After I export an obj file the materials without "principled bsdf" disappear in the exported model, but in render preview I can see those materials. And in an exported fbx file, if i try to export also the "empty files", the exported model looks deformed.

Comment: and for the obj file?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: and for the emtpy files?

Comment: those guides are not for my problem idk why u post those links here...